# Run distributed tensor flow using Keras with fit_generator

Tags: tensorflow, keras, distributed-computing

Is there a way to run a Keras model based on model.fit_generator() on several machines?

I defined my model using

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(...)
```

so I have no lower-level access to my tf.Variables and cannot use

```
with tf.device("/job:ps/task:1"):
  weights_2 = tf.Variable(...)
  biases_2 = tf.Variable(...)
```

or

```
with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
    worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
    cluster=cluster)):
```

as explained in [Google's distributed tensor flow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed#create_a_tftrainserver_instance_in_each_task).

I found a way to do it [using Keras + Spark](https://github.com/maxpumperla/elephas), but is it a simpler way?